# Need to enable both Landscape and portrait mode using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test mobile devices in both landscape and portrait mode using javascript. So i need to check which orientation is working now and do some process and same process want to do in another orientation also.

I want to do some process in landscape and portrait mode

Answer (score 0):

```
let portrait = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

portrait.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    if(e.matches) {
        // Portrait mode
    } else {
        // Landscape
    }
})
```

Comment: If condition is true want to perform some execution know the same set of process will be in else part also that's my question.make sense??

Comment: you can reuse use the code in both if and else places

Comment: But if we have 100+ lines of code it supposed to be repeat again is not a good practice know

Comment: u can write a function and u can call these thing in both places